# Why are ANSI escape sequences only printing properly in Maven and not otherwise

Tags: java, windows, maven, ansi-escape

I have been making a game in java, and the game is just text based in the terminal using sys.out, so I learned about using ansi escape characters to add colouring to the text to make it more readable. Additionally, the project was created with Maven, as there was a library I wanted to use that was only available through Maven, but now that I gotten further in the project I realize the library will not be needed.

I thought that if I don't need Maven, I can just create the project without it just with the normal JDK tools like javac and then java to run it. I also wanted to do this because a lot of Unicode character don't print properly when running the program with Maven (im not sure why as when I make a test program without Maven these characters print just fine), so this would allow me more options for the graphics of the game as I could use character beyond just the basic ascii set. The issue is when I compile and run the program without Maven, the ansi escape character don't colour the text, but are instead printed literally.

Here is it when run with Maven:
[image: How it displays in Maven]

And this is it just with plain Java:
[image: How it displays when just run with Java]

This isn't a very big issue to me as I had already resigned myself to just using basic ascii and Maven, but I was moreso just curious why this happens. I have read that ansi may not work in Windows at all (?), but then that just makes me more confused as to why it was working with Maven. does Maven emulate a unix terminal while running or something?

Comment: *does Maven emulate a unix terminal while running or something?* I think the (too) simple answer to that is, yes. I think this will be via its logging framework and fusesource `JAnsi`. I don't do Maven with Windows so can't say for certain